# Regex - How to select everything when the word is not contained

Tags: regex

Say that I have this text

> I need to think of something to write here. 
>   I am an alumni of the college. 
>   The blue cat is blue the red cat is red.

I want to be able to select everything if the word "student" (ignoring case) does NOT exist in the text. Therefore, I need something to go beyond the first line. I originally had something like

```
/(?:[^student]).*/
```

but it isn't working correctly. I am not sure what "flavor" of Regex I am using but it is with PHP and in the backend of a Drupal site.

Thank you!

Comment: What about "If matched, use match, if not use whole string?"

Comment: What about `^(?!.*student).*$` or `^(?:(?!student).)*$` ?

Comment: lol i was thinking the same thing

Comment: You clearly don't understand what `[^student]` means in a regex. `[]` is not used to group a string, it's used to specify a character class.

Comment: @ctwheels those both work but I think the problem I'm getting is from drupal now.

Comment: @ctwheels I actually think these aren't working for me, but not sure why. They also don't work correctly when I check using regexr.com

Comment: @MonaNM it's a negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match. So having `.*student` will ensure `student` doesn't exist anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

As suggested by ctwheels comment, the regexp you have written `(?:[^student]).*` is not doing what you think it does. Lets break down your attempt to illustrate the problem:

`(?:          )`  <--- this part is a **non-capturing group**

`[^student]`   <--- this part matches **a single character** not present in the list

`.*` <--- matches any character (except for line terminators)

I.e, your bracket expression is the same as `[^tneduts]` or `[^neduts]`or even `[^denstu]`. It doesn't look for a word!

**Solution**

What you want to do instead, is using a **negative lookahead**. like this `^(?!.*student).*$`. Let's break it down.

`^`  <--- position at start of the string

`(?!.*student)` <--- look for anything followed by student, don't match if found

`.*` <--- take everything on the line unless the negative lookahead is in effect.

`$` <--– position at the end of the string

Comment: is there a way I could replace .* in your solution to get it to search and select multiple lines?

Comment: You could try to match newlines explicitly but I avoid regexp for multiline parsing. If you have longer texts I suggest you look for the word 'student' in the entire file instead using a simple line by line character matcher like [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).